# Laravel delete pivot table column when deleting one of the main tables columns

Tags: laravel

I have articles table and article_categories table and I made a pivot table between the two tables, but when deleting an article it says

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`aqaraty`.`article_article_category`, CONSTRAINT `article_article_category_article_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`article_id`) REFERENCES `articles` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `articles` where `id` = 9)
```

how to delete the pivot row with deleting an article?

Answer (score 0):

The issue come from foreign id. In this case, you have two options.
First, you can delete the record from the pivot table firstly, then the article.
Second and optional one, you can add an additional function to the pivot migration table like:

```
$table->foreign('article_id')
      ->references('id')->on('articles')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

If you add the `->onDelete('cascade');` function, when the record to which it is linked is deleted, it also ensures that it is deleted.